# Django get text function causes attempt to save unchanged inlines

Tags: python, django, validation, admin

So I have this scenario where when I add the Translation get text function ("from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _" ) to my model. When I try to save the record, it gives me a ***"this field is required error"*** on all the "number" fields of the unchanged inline records.

Unchanged in-lines should not be saved but when I add the import for this library, it tries to save these unchanged in-lines in my admin page.

Thankfully, because number cannot be blank, it aborts the save. But the client also cannot be able to use his system!

I have seen a few django tickets but I am confused as to why the get text function is causing an issue. Below is my model.py and admin.py scripts which cause the error.

model.py and admin.py script **that DO WORK and successfully** save the database entry in the admin webpage.

**admin.py**

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
# Register your models here.
from simulation.models import parts, repair_jobs

class partsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = parts

class repair_jobsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [partsInline]

admin.site.register(repair_jobs, repair_jobsAdmin)
```

**model.py**

```
#model.py
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class repair_jobs(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s, %s" %(self.customer, self.model)

class parts(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(repair_jobs)
    number = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False)

    qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2, default = 1.00, blank = False, null = False)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 2, default = 0.00, blank = True, nulll = True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s: %s, %s" % (self.job, self.number, self.qty)
```

The above code successfully executes and upon pressing "save" is successfully able to save the database

**However the below code fails**.

**model.py and admin.py script that DON'T WORK and upon saving the database result in the error ":** "This Field is Required" 
**model.py:**

```
 #model.py
 from django.db import models
 from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
 # Create your models here.

class repair_jobs(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s, %s" %(self.customer, self.model)

class parts(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(repair_jobs)
    number = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False)
    qty = models.DecimalField(_("quantity"), max_digits=3, decimal_places=0, default="1",     blank=False, null=False, help_text=_("How many are needed?") 
    cost = models.DecimalField(_("cost price"), max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True,   null=True, default="0", help_text=_("Price paid per unit") )
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s: %s, %s" % (self.job, self.number, self.qty)
```

the admin.py script is not changed from the code above so using the same admin.py script as above this gives the error ***"This Field is Required"***

The only difference is i'm using translations in one case and not in the other.

Any ideas as to why this error is occurring when I click save?

here is a link to a django ticket I also found that might be related to the above problem:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9373

Note: Im using Django 1.6 and Python 2.7